# Match a value from array of values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I have a query like this :

```
$sql = "
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            tbl_emp_data
        WHERE
            company_qualification = '$q'
    ";
```

Now my `company_qualification` field is not a single value ,instead its a words separated by commas like `BSc,BA,BCom` etc . And the value `$q` is a single value say `BA` . So how can I search the company data from the value `$q` . I can not use `LIKE` since its going to match fields like `BA` and `BBA` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
$sql = "
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            tbl_emp_data
        WHERE        
           FIND_IN_SET($q,company_qualification)
    ";
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tbl_emp_data WHERE FIND_IN_SET(B.A,company_qualification) LIMIT 0, 10 `

Comment: `B.A ` is a string and must be surrounded by the single or double quote. put the `'$q'` in single quote and also make sure you are escaping user inputs before substituting them with query.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            tbl_emp_data
        WHERE
            company_qualification IN ('".implode("','",$q)."')
    ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_emp_data WHERE company_qualification IN ('BSc', 'BA', 'BCom');
```

Comment: Ah, Shakti Singh got there first. I don't know the difference between IN and FIND_IN_SET though.